# How to automatically obtain which endpoint was a request sent to in django?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to include a feature in my django REST API where whenever sends a request to an endpoint / url that url along with the post data should be saved to the sqlite database. post data is already being saved but how do I obtain and save the url from which the request is coming from? I am using django rest framework

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one approach, Write a middle layer, In which you will get all the requests coming to the APP. So read the data from the request and write into the table.

To write the custom middle layer follow the below document.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: I basically just want to save the endpoint which is being accessed to the database for record keeping

Comment: If it is the case, You know that in which endpoint you are accessing the DB, that time access the URL from the request object and write it into the table. You can access the URL from request object like below.
```request.build_absolute_uri``